# How to make images blink simultaneously?

Tags: android, animation

I have 5 images, I want img1 & img2 to blink simultaneously for 3 sec, then img3 & img4 to blink simultaneously for 3 sec. However, I want img5 to remain static for 3 sec and then the whole process starts from beginning again.

Part of my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

 ...
    img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    img3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    img4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    img5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);


    img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ....

    anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(500); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
    anim.setStartOffset(30);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(20);

    ...

   img1.startAnimation(anim);

    AnimationListener animListener = new AnimationListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img2.startAnimation(anim2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

    }; 
}
```

Comment: img5 pauses, but the img1&2 img3&4 are not blinking simultaneously. Still need help in resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Handler` to keep img5 static for 3 seconds and then start the animation.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // animateImg5();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much... this gave me an idea on what to use.